# Sorting Issue in DynamoDB: ScanIndexForward Not Working as Expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB with email as the partition key and created_at as the sort key, where created_at is a numeric field representing the date converted to a timestamp.

When fetching data, I want to sort it by the created_at field. However, setting the scanindexforward parameter to either true or false does not result in sorted data. Additionally, when adding items to the table, they are not stored in the order I expect, but rather in an arbitrary order, and I am unsure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption here is that you are using a `Scan` API, which does not sort data across all partition keys.

In DynamoDB, items which share the same partition key are sorted in ascending order of their sort key. In your case, an `email` key would be guaranteed to be sorted by `created_at` attribute in ascending order.

This `Query` request written in Python would guarantee me that all of the emails for `someone@example.com` would be returned in ascending order of timestamp.

```
    response = client.query(
        TableName=table_name, 
        KeyConditionExpression='#email=:email',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':email':{'S':'someone@example.com'}},   
        ExpressionAttributeNames={'#email':'email'}
    )
```